# Returning the results of a LINQ query as a complex model

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have the following LINQ query that I want to return as a model with related joins etc all in place.

```
      var query = (from wi in context.WorkItems
                     join mi in context.MaintenanceItems
                         on new { Id = wi.MaintenanceItemID }
                         equals new { Id = mi.MaintenanceItemID }
                     join p in context.Properties 
                         on new { Id = mi.PropertyID }
                         equals new { Id = p.PropertyID }
                     join l in context.Locations 
                          on new { Id = p.LocationID }
                          equals new { Id = l.LocationID }
                     join c in context.Categories 
                          on new { Id = mi.CategoryID }
                          equals new { Id = c.CategoryID }
                     join sc in context.SubCategories 
                          on new { Id = mi.SubCategoryID }
                          equals new { Id = sc.SubCategoryID }
                     join pl in context.PickLists 
                          on new { Id = wi.PriorityFlag, V = "Priority" }
                          equals new { Id = pl.ValueKey, V = pl.ValueType }
                     where wi.AssignedTo1 == username           
                    orderby wi.PriorityFlag descending, wi.PriorityIndex, wi.WorkItemID 
                    select new {
                        wi.WorkItemID, 
                        wi.PriorityFlag,
                        wi.PriorityIndex,
                        wi.CompletionDateTime,
                        l.LocationName,
                        p.PropertyFullName ,
                        wi.AssignedTo1,
                        wi.AssignedTo2,
                        wi.AssignedTo3,
                        c.CategoryName,
                        sc.SubCategoryName,
                        PriorityDesc = pl.ValueTitle 
                    });
```

My model consists of a WorkItem entity which the query can return multiples of, with then related entities filling in the descriptive values for all the foreign keys etc.

Obviously using the query I have created an anonymous type, but I am not sure how to turn it back into the fully fleshed out known types I need?

Answer (score 0):

> I have created an anonymous type, but I am not sure how to turn it back into the fully fleshed out known types I need?

Instead of projecting selected elements into a new type, use [Eager Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/) to `Include()` the full related entities in your result.

Also instead of projecting individual scalar properties in your anonymous type, you can project whole entities.

Comment: I was doing that, but I have a shared reference table (PickLists in the code) where I store multiple sets of reference / lookup data - I cna't seem to do that using Include() so that's why I went with a manually constructed query.

Comment: See updated answer.  And consider modeling PickLists as seperate entities using Table-Per-Hierarchy inheritance.  It's really an anti-pattern in the database too, but you can sometimes fix it in EF.

Comment: Thanks - even if I return the whole entities will not the result of the query still be an anonymous type? I am looking into TPH but if I have a generic table with a columns of ValueType (discriminator), ValueKey and ValueDescription for example how do I link that to a table with a column called PriorityID?

Comment: You would create an entity `Priority : PickList` with, and then create a Navigation Property to that entity, configuring `PriorityId` as the Foreign Key Property.  Or create a bunch of views in teh database for the different lookups, or (even better) create seperate tables.  You can even keep your single PickList table, and use that to update the seperate reference tables.

Comment: Do you know what I think I may just split the tables as suggested. I can't seem to work out the navigation property - I see the HasForeignKey option suggested but cannot even get that to work currently.